# Filter integer column endswith hundreds in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Given a small dataset `df` as follows:

```
[{'id': 110000, 'name': 'Derek Wood'},
 {'id': 110101, 'name': 'Thomas Butler'},
 {'id': 110105, 'name': 'Nicholas Crawford'},
 {'id': 120000, 'name': 'Brian Jenkins'},
 {'id': 120101, 'name': 'Eric Stokes'},
 {'id': 220000, 'name': 'Christopher Mccarty'},
 {'id': 220100, 'name': 'Christian Griffith'},
 {'id': 220102, 'name': 'Antonio Webb'}]
```

or:

```
       id                 name
0  110000           Derek Wood
1  110101        Thomas Butler
2  110105    Nicholas Crawford
3  120000        Brian Jenkins
4  120101          Eric Stokes
5  220000  Christopher Mccarty
6  220100   Christian Griffith
7  220102         Antonio Webb
```

How could filter `id` endswith hundreds? The expected result will like:

```
       id                 name
0  110000           Derek Wood
3  120000        Brian Jenkins
5  220000  Christopher Mccarty
6  220100   Christian Griffith
```

My trial code, it works but I'm looking for a alternative solution without converting the dtype of `id`:

```
df['id'] = df['id'].astype(str)
df[df['id'].str.endswith('00')]
```

Comment: What is the dtype of the id column?

Comment: The original was `int64`

Comment: Do you need id to be a string for some reason? Could you use modulus instead `df[df['id'] % 100 == 0]`?

Comment: I convert it to string in order to use `str.endswith('00')`, I think your solution is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `modulus` which is `%` in pandas. It returns the remainder value after division. For your use case, you want to return the rows of `id` divided by `100` and its remainder is `0`.

```
condition = (df["id"]%100 == 0)
resulted_df = df[condition]
```